# Why do my hidden photos still show up in the Albums?

Tags: photos.app

I have a bunch of photos that I have hidden, but I can still see them in my albums. Is there a way to hide them totally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete it! Hide works only for moments, so in moments hidden photos won't appear

Comment: Thank you XD. It is a bit disappointing, Iphoto did not work this way. :_(

Comment: Ye I know, the new photos app work as iPhone photos app...

Comment: yeah, completely defeats the purpose of hiding photos :/